# Getting data from HTML Input elements for Django Form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a designed form in my template and i want to use it instead of Django Forms. I created my model and view class and urls, but I don't know how to receive and use form's data. I've already studied [Rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)  but I want to use my form inputs and labels and only need the data.

Please be aware that class and models work perfectly and I can use data if I use {{ form }} in my template instead of html code below

Here's my class in my forms.py:

```
class Reserve(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='نام و نام خانوادگی', max_length=100)
    phone = forms.CharField(label='شماره تماس', max_length=11)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='ایمیل', max_length=100)
    occasion = forms.CharField(label='مناسبت', max_length=100)
    month = forms.CharField(label='ماه', max_length=100)
    day = forms.CharField(label='روز', max_length=100)
    week = forms.CharField(label='روز هفته')
    time = forms.CharField(label='ساعت', max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(label='توضیحات')
```

Here's my function in views.py:

```
def add_reserve(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Reserve(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           name = form.cleaned_data['name']
           phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
           email = form.cleaned_data['email']
           occasion = form.cleaned_data['occasion']
           month = form.cleaned_data['month']
           day = form.cleaned_data['day']
           week = form.cleaned_data['week']
           time = form.cleaned_data['time']
           message = form.cleaned_data['message']
           reserve = MangReserve(name=name, phone=phone, email=email, occasion=occasion, month=month, day=day,
                              week=week, time=time, message=message)
           reserve.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        form = Reserve()

return render(request, 'mang/temp.html', {'form': form})
```

And finally a part of my form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'mang:add-reserve' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
                        <input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="نام و نام خانوادگی" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="phone" class="sr-only">Name</label>
                        <input id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="موبایل" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="ایمیل" type="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="occasion" class="sr-only">occasion</label>
                        <input id="occasion" class="form-control" placeholder="مناسبت" type="text">
                    </div>.......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got the template from, but all the fields are missing the vital `name` attribute. Without that, the browser simply won't send any data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please add "name" attribute to all the HTML input elements matching your form fields, which I think will solve your problem. An example:

```
 <input id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="ایمیل" type="email">
```

The above input element is given name="email", which matches your form email field.

Once you do this for all the input elements, you should receive the data in request.POST and the form will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much...  what a shame i didn't pay attention to check if form attributes are correct or not

Comment: Glad it helped.